# Cross domain communication?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jsonp

I'm building a small app in javascript for use on a website I don't own. The app includes a few options that change the site a bit. I want to be able to add a login system and chat. Because of the cross-domain policies, I know I can't do regular ajax. The only other thing I know how to do is jsonp by appending script elements to the webpage.

If I were to do a chat system that updated each second via a script element, would that be too resource heavy? If I do use jsonp, should I update one script element for new requests, or append new ones each time?

Is jsonp even the way to go with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a W3C Working Draft that defines how the browser and server must communicate when accessing sources across origins. The basic idea behind CORS is to use custom HTTP headers to allow both the browser and the server to know enough about each other to determine if the request or response should succeed or fail.

For a simple request, one that uses either GET or POST with no custom headers and whose body is text/plain, the request is sent with an extra header called Origin. The Origin header contains the origin (protocol, domain name, and port) of the requesting page so that the server can easily determine whether or not it should serve a response. An example Origin header might look like this:

```
Origin: http://www.webiste.com
```

If the server decides that the request should be allowed, it sends a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header echoing back the same origin that was sent or “*” if it’s a public resource. For example:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.webiste.com
```

If this header is missing, or the origins don’t match, then the browser disallows the request. If all is well, then the browser processes the request. Note that neither the requests nor responses include cookie information.

All of the previously mentioned browsers support these simple requests. Firefox 3.5+, Safari 4+, and Chrome all support usage through the XMLHttpRequest object. When attempting to open a resource on a different origin, this behavior automatically gets triggered without any extra code. For example:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("get", "http://www.webiste.com/some_resource/", true);
xhr.onload = function(){  //instead of onreadystatechange
    //do something
};
xhr.send(null);
```

To do the same in Internet Explorer 8, you’ll need to use the `XDomainRequest` object in the same manner:

```
var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
xdr.open("get", "http://www.webiste.com/some_resource/");
xdr.onload = function(){
    //do something
};
xdr.send();
```

The Mozilla team suggests in their post about CORS that you should check for the existence of the withCredentials property to determine if the browser supports CORS via XHR. You can then couple with the existence of the XDomainRequest object to cover all browsers:

```
function createCORSRequest(method, url){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if ("withCredentials" in xhr){
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined"){
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
    } else {
        xhr = null;
    }
       return xhr;
    }

var request = createCORSRequest("get", "http:/www.webiste.com/");
if (request){
    request.onload = function(){
        //do something with request.responseText
    };
    request.send();
}
```

The `XMLHttpRequest` object in Firefox, Safari, and Chrome has similar enough interfaces to the IE `XDomainRequest` object that this pattern works fairly well. The common interface properties/methods are:

- abort() – use to stop a request that’s already in progress.
- onerror – use instead of onreadystatechange to detect errors.
- onload – use instead of onreadystatechange to detect successes.
- responseText – use to get contents of response.
- send() – use to send the request.

Comment: This didn't help much and you didn't even credit your source... http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/

Answer (score 0):

The server that will use your application will need to add the domain of your application to a cross-domain policy file.  This is usually an XML file that lives in the web root, but the exact nature depends on whether that server is .NET, PHP, etc.

After that, you will be able to make ajax calls from your script with no problems.

IMO, dynamically adding script tags is asking for trouble, especially if the DOM is not aware of what you are doing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Seriously? I thought it was the browser and the server preventing the requests. Do you have any more information on how I could do this?

Comment: A quick google search turned this up: http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-tips/quick-tip-a-guide-to-cross-domain-policy-files/

Comment: Please let me know if that doesn't help you out and I will try to get you the rest of the way.

Comment: That's for flash though, is there anything for javascript?

Comment: Hey Walkerneo--maybe this tut can help: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html.

Comment: That last tutorial is for a PHP middle tier.  I don't know what middle-tier language/framework you are using so if you give me more context I would be glad to try and help.